# Greedy Algorithm: building the tallest tower stealing the less bricks

Tags: python, algorithm, greedy

A group of m children try to build the tallest possible tower. Every kid has the bricks of different size. The first child has w1,1 , ... , w1,n1, the second w2,1, ... w2,n2 etc. The kids went to eat dinner, but one clever child stayed. Now he has the only change to pick up some bricks from other children so that he has the highest tower. Show the quickest algorithm to solve this problem, which takes the little number of bricks (note that the number wi,j can be very large). Towels treat as a sets, not stack (we can take any bricks that we want from the particular tower).

I was thinking all day for solving this problem, but for all solution I created, I also see a situation, when they do not work.
I tried use Greedy Algorithm. The best idea, which I have is take the bricks from towers, which are bigger that the clever child. If the size of taken bricks + tower of clever child is still less, take the biggest bricks from all towers.
Unfortunately, problem is when we have sets like this:
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2,2,2,2], [7,4,1], [9, 2]
and tower of clever child has size 13

Have anyone idea or hints how to solve this task?

Comment: In principle, take one brick at a time from the tallest tower, continuously re-evaluating which tower is tallest. Then add mathematics for speed.

Comment: I thought about it, but when we have: [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], [5,5,5,1], [6,6,6,1] - the minimum is 4 (bricks 6,6,6,5) :/

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. Take the “most valuable” brick each time, where bricks in the tallest tower are valued at double their size. There are some tricky cases when the largest towers become similar in size though.

Comment: Unfortunately, this task has a lot cases to consider and it's hard to write the correct program for all. Thank you so much for help!